# I need to convert this code to supabase, but there is an error in the join

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, postgresql, supabase

I need to convert the following SQL code to the subbase using docs API integration (I found almost nothing in the documentation)

```
SELECT * FROM public.usuario JOIN public.usuario_empresa ON public.usuario.id = public.usuario_empresa.usuario_id JOIN public.empresa ON public.empresa.id = public.usuario_empresa.empresa_id;
```

The AI ​​itself recommends the following usage

```
const { data, error } = await supabase   .from('public.usuario')   .select('*')   .join('public.usuario_empresa', { 'public.usuario.id': 'public.usuario_empresa.usuario_id' })   .join('public.empresa', { 'public.empresa.id': 'public.usuario_empresa.empresa_id' });
```

but i am getting the error:

```
12 | .from('public.usuario')
13 | .select('*')

> 14 | .join('public.usuario_empresa', { 'public.usuario.id': 'public.usuario_empresa.usuario_id' })

     |     ^

15 | .join('public.empresa', { 'public.empresa.id': 'public.usuario_empresa.empresa_id' });
```

The tables are:

```
CREATE TABLE public.usuario (
id integer NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
nome character varying(100) NOT NULL,
email character varying(100) NOT NULL,
telefone character varying(20),
data_nascimento date,
cidade_nascimento character varying(100),
CONSTRAINT usuario_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE public.empresa (
id integer NOT NULL GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
nome character varying(100) NOT NULL,
cnpj character varying(20) NOT NULL,
endereco character varying(200) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT empresa_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE public.usuario_empresa (
usuario_id integer NOT NULL,
empresa_id integer NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT usuario_empresa_pkey PRIMARY KEY (usuario_id, empresa_id),
CONSTRAINT fk_usuario FOREIGN KEY (usuario_id) REFERENCES public.usuario(id),
CONSTRAINT fk_empresa FOREIGN KEY (empresa_id) REFERENCES public.empresa(id)
);
```

(I found almost nothing in the documentation about join)

Answer (score 0):

based on what you envious you need to do a 'join' between user and company in this case the code would look like this:

```js
const { data, error } = await supabase
        .from('usuario_empresa')
        .select(`
            usuario:usuario_id ( id, nome, email, telefone, data_nascimento, cidade_nascimento ),
            empresa:empresa_id ( id, nome, cnpj, endereco )
        `)
```

if your company_user table had an id, you could also capture it in the following way:

```js
const { data, error } = await supabase
        .from('usuario_empresa')
        .select(`
            id "<---- this would be the id of the user_company table if you wanted to get it together (at least in the case I used it was not mandatory)"

            usuario:usuario_id ( id, nome, email, telefone, data_nascimento, cidade_nascimento ),
            empresa:empresa_id ( id, nome, cnpj, endereco )
        `)
```